# Is it possible to have multiple *Find* buffers in emacs?

Tags: dired

If I execute a `M-x find-name-dired` command the output is a `*Find*` buffer containing the results.

However if I perform a subsequent `find-name-dired` the contents of the `*Find*` buffer are overwritten with the latest output.

Is there a means to execute multiple `find-name-dired` commands and keep the output buffer of each?

In other words, have multiple `*Find*` buffers?

Comment: Please don't post the same question to both StackOverflow and emacs.SE - choose *one*. Please delete one of the posts. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code, `find-name-dired` delegates to `find-dired`.

Looking at the `find-dired` code, it opens a buffer with name `"*Find*"`. From its source:

```
(get-buffer-create "*Find*")
```

So if we rename the first buffer we made, the second call to `find-name-dired` will not touch it. You can rename the buffer with <kbd>M-x rename-buffer</kbd> (lets you choose a name) or <kbd>M-x rename-uniquely</kbd> (adds a numerical suffix `<2>`, `<3>`, …).

Rather than renaming by hand, here's a wrapper function around `find-name-dired` that changes the buffer name after it's ran. Note that it will reuse any preexisting buffer called `*Find*`, so prior searches ran with `find-name-dired` or other find commands will go away.

```
(defun find-name-dired-with-unique-buffer-name (dir pattern)
  "Search DIR recursively for files matching the globbing pattern PATTERN,
and run Dired on those files.
PATTERN is a shell wildcard (not an Emacs regexp) and need not be quoted.
The default command run (after changing into DIR) is

    find . -name \\='PATTERN\\=' -ls

See `find-name-arg' to customize the arguments."
    (interactive
     "DFind-name (directory): \nsFind-name (filename wildcard): ")
    (find-name-dired dir pattern)
    (let ((buffer-name (format "*Find: %s in %s*" pattern dir)))
      "If we previously searched for the same thing, kill that buffer for reuse"
      (when (get-buffer buffer-name)
        (kill-buffer buffer-name))

      ;;we are left in a buffer called "*Find*"
      (rename-buffer buffer-name)))
```

Comment: Thanks!  The only weakness of this solution is that if we search for the same pattern in two directories, the first is killed.  That can be worked-around by also adding the directory to the buffer name.

Comment: @Realraptor sure, why not? Added.

Answer (score 2):

If you use library [**`find-dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) then the buffer used is *not* `*Find*`.  Instead, it has same name (using `directory-file-name`) as argument `DIR` (the directory).

So if you change directory then you get a different buffer.

If that's not enough then you can always use hook `find-dired-hook` to rename the buffer each time (or whatever).